# Trouble connecting VS 2010, 2012, and 2013 to azure devops server 2019

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am facing an error when I try to connect Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 to our Azure DevOps Server 2019 instance.  In each of those versions when I attempt to add the server I get an error

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server.
>
> Technical Information:  The request was aborted:  Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

If I try to connect again after that I see this message.

> The underlying connection was closed:  An unexpected error occurred on a send.

I am able to connect without error on VS 2015, 2017 and 2019. I am having this problem on multiple machines.  The machines are on Win 10 and Win 2012R2.  Also from these machines I can hit the TFS https web sites, team projects just fine.

Comment: Do you set up HTTPS with SSL for the Azure DevOps server 2019? Do the VS can connect to server install on the same machine as the VS can't connect to server? Do you use the same credential to connect to the server?

Comment: Yes we did setup https.  On the same machine all VS can connect.  Different credentials and same credentials have the problem connecting.  I do have one machine that is able to connect on VS2010 without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix.  Looks like it is a TLS issue.

Run this from powershell:

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32